# call() of function with arguments

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, function, components

I have a component that I hand over a function

```
public var func : Function;
```

Now the function is a function that has parameters in its signature

```
public function myFunction(s : String) : void {
   doSomething(s);
}
```

from my component I can call the function with

```
func.call();
```

Can someone tell me how to invoke the function with its parameters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should either be able to do this:

```
func("foo");
```

or

```
func.call(this, "foo");
```

or

```
func.apply(this, ["foo"]);
```

Have a look at the documentation for the [Function](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Function.html) object in AS3 documentation.